# Placing data frames right after each other in a pdf

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices data.list and I'm trying to display them all on a pdf right after one another, with titles. the elements of the list are indexed by the elements of a list called row.vector.

Here's my code:

```
pdf("data.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)
for (i in 1:length(row.vector)) {
    grid.arrange(tableGrob(data.list[[row.vector[[i]]]], gp=gpar(fontsize=6)), main = row.vector[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

There are two problems with this.
 - All the matrices are displayed on separate pages, despite the fact that none of them are big enough to warrant a page. I want them displayed right after another.
 - The titles are at the top of the page and I want them to be right over the table.
I also want to put graphs in, displayed in between tables (no tables or graphs next to each other horizontally).

Here are test lists:

```
row.vector <- list("first", "second", "third")
a <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
a[1,] <- c(3,4,5)
a[2,] <- c(6,7,8)
a[3,] <- c(1,1,1)
a[4,] <- c(1,1,1)
b<- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
b[1,] <- c("a","x","y")
b[2,] <- c("d","d","d")
c <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
c[,1] <- 1:10
c[,2] <- 11:20
data.list <- list("first" = a,"second"=b,"third"=c)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `grid.arrange` one at a time like that. Put all the grobs in a list, and then do `do.call(grid.arrange,my_list)`. That solves the multi-page problem. But more generally, I suspect this project of yours is going to require more knowledge of **grid** than you're going to pick up simply by asking isolated questions on SO. You might want to invest in Paul Murrell's book.

Comment: (I say that because based on your description, `grid.arrange` really isn't going to be suitable down the road. You're going to need to learn how to do your own layouts in **grid** using viewports and everything.)

Comment: @joran that works great for when there are three, but when there are four, it arranges in a rectangle, and as I add more eventually they start to overlap. Is there any way to make it so they're just top down, basically in a grid arrangement but with 1 column. I'm fine with multiple pages but only when they're necessary.

Also, thanks for the book advice, I'll look into that.

Comment: This may be a silly question but how do you add a parameter to a function in do.call?

Comment: Have you tried: `do.call( function(x) {fun(x, parm=parameter)}, arglist)`. I know that `mapply` has a "moreArgs" argument that lets you pass parameters, but I imagine something with an anonymous functions or a named-wrapper function might be needed with `do.call`.